# Why does d3 not work properly with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, powerbi

Currently I want to learn TypeScript to create custom PowerBI visuals. My problem is that I have no idea about anything in this subject, and that seemingly a lot of the guides on TypeScript+d3 are outdated. I get a lot of errors when copying the code from the guide. For example, that methods in the guide don't exist (ScaleBand -> Bandwidth).

I've installed all the modules (d3, @types/d3), and have created the right folder structure.

When I compile my code it tells me that variables are implicitly any. Now I want to avoid using "any", for best practice reasons, but how do I know what datatype is returned by a specific d3 method? Since JavaScript doesn't really care about datatypes I compiled my code but it doesn't work - meaning, that the model/svg doesn't show up on my html-website. It stays blank.

Any help, or guidance as to what/where I can accomplish this?
These are the guides I tried following:

https://square.github.io/intro-to-d3/data-binding/ (I did this in typescript, the compiled javascript code is the same as in the guide)

https://hstefanski.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/creating-a-chart-with-d3-and-typescript-part-1/

My TypeScript file:

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/@types/d3/index.d.ts"/>
import * as d3 from "d3"; //Importing d3-Module

interface ISales {
  product: string;
  count: number;
}
let sales: ISales[] = [
  { product: "Hoodie", count: 7 },
  { product: "Jacket", count: 6 },
  { product: "Snuggie", count: 9 }
];

let svg: any = d3.select("svg"); //Selecting <svg> elements
svg.size(); //Printing count of elements in svg

let rects: any = svg.selectAll("rect").data(sales); //Selecting <rect> elements
rects.size(); //Printing count of elements in rect

//Placeholder nodes for each datum
let newRects: any = rects.enter();

//Getting highest count
let maxCount: any = d3.max(sales, function(d, i) {
  return d.count;
});

//Setting x-axis  --  Range is in pixels, domain is amount of elements
let x: any = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 300]).domain([0, maxCount]);

//Setting y-axis
let y: any = d3.scaleOrdinal().range([300, 0]).domain(
  sales.map(function(d, i) {
    return d.product;
  })
);

newRects
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", x(0))
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return y(d.product);
  })
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
  .attr("width", function(d, i) {
    return x(d.count);
  });
```

My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>d3-Modeling</title>
        <script src=".../d3Modeling.js> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <svg width="300" height="100">

        </svg>


    </body>

</html>
```

The compiled js file:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

///<reference path="../node_modules/@types/d3/index.d.ts"/>

var d3 = require("d3"); //Importing d3-Module

var sales = [
  { product: "Hoodie", count: 7 },
  { product: "Jacket", count: 6 },
  { product: "Snuggie", count: 9 }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg"); //Selecting <svg> elements
svg.size(); //Printing count of elements in svg

var rects = svg.selectAll("rect").data(sales); //Selecting <rect> elements
rects.size(); //Printing count of elements in rect

//Placeholder nodes for each datum
var newRects = rects.enter();

//Getting highest count
var maxCount = d3.max(sales, function(d, i) {
  return d.count;
});

//Setting x-axis  --  Range is in pixels, domain is amount of elements
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 300]).domain([0, maxCount]);

//Setting y-axis
var y = d3.scaleOrdinal().range([300, 0]).domain(
  sales.map(function(d, i) {
    return d.product;
  })
);

newRects
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", x(0))
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return y(d.product);
  })
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
  .attr("width", function(d, i) {
    return x(d.count);
  });
```

Comment: Even though TypeScript compiler blames about declarations being of `any` type, it compiles. By the way, you didn't tell us what 'does not work'.

Comment: The model doesn't show up on the website. I edited my original comment.

Comment: check your script tag: <script src=".../d3Modeling.js> </script>   ,,, it should be something like <script src="../d3Modeling.js"> </script>, maybe?

Comment: I have tried various combinations for the path - none of them worked.